# How can I open a new window to login from Asp Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have been googling for sometime, but in vain. I need to return a View from my Web Api. When I click on a button, it should open a new small window that requires the user to login. How can I achieve this ASP Web Api ?

Comment: you cannot return a view from web api, you might be looking for returning view from mvc and calling a web api method once user clicks login button!

Comment: Yes that's it ! How can I do so ?

Comment: Please try writing the code and come up with questions when you are facing an issue.

Answer (score 0):

you're thinking in a very non API way.

An API's job is not to return views but data. If you want to authenticate a user against an API then you have to use an API specific way.

An example would be something like OWIN or anything else. There are many libraries around that do this, just do a search and pick whatever satisfies your requirements.